# velocity templates files for localization

Tags: spring, jsp, localization

I am adjusting messageSource to support multi language. I have some velocity templates files (.vm). I wonder how can I adjust message codes for these files.

Now I add message code for localization like this.

```
<spring:message code="user.name"/>
```

But I cannot try this for .vm files. How can I use this code for .vm files? 
If possible, please let me know.

Thanks.